# Android Studio XML using marginRight with API 17

Tags: android, xml

I have a RelativeLayout and I am using `android:layout_marginEnd="170dp"`
and Android Studio is telling me:

> To support older version than API 17(project specifies 15) you should
>   also add

`android:layout_marginRight="170dp"`

It's not an error, it compiles correctly, but I don't understand this hint. Why should I use marginRight?  Why not marginLeft? 
Can anyone explain me the secret behind this?
I looked for other answers but I still didn't get it.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`android:layout_marginEnd` was added in API 17 for better support for right-to-left languages. However, earlier versions of Android prior to API 17 don't recognize this tag, so your need to add `android:layout_marginRight` as well.

Comment: out of curiosity: when one adds a `layout_marginRight` and use a right-to-left language, isn't then the start margin wrong?

Comment: I've never tested behavior myself, but it probably differs  per device, as the specified behavior isn't clear. IIRC you can set a default locale for your app, and some devices may assume that if the default locale is a left to right language and you specify android:layout_marginRight, and the device has a right to left language, it may automatically swap it. But other devices may not do this. My guess is that android:layout_marginEnd was added to avoid this fragmented behavior and allow the developer to specify exactly how it should appear.